# Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.jfrog.artifactory']

Tags: plugins, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle 6.7.1 and trying to apply the latest version of the plugin 'com.jfrog.artifactory', but get this error -

> No signature of method:  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.RealizableTaskCollection.configureEach() is applicable for argument types: (org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPluginBase$_addModuleInfoTask_closure2) values: [org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPluginBase$_addModuleInfoTask_closure2@72132197]

This is what I have in my build.gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.18.2"
    }
}
```

I also tried to use 4.18.1 and 4.18.0, but got the same error. Help please!

Comment: See the discussion in: https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues/338
The current solution is to downgrade to 4.15.1

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that post @Prostagma. I ended up upgrading gradle and using 4.24.14 version of jfrog artifactory and that seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

your apply plugin line should be after the buildscript block

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.18.2"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin for your response. I my gradle file i have the way you suggested, I mistakenly pasted in the wrong place.